# stuck while running angular application in IE11

Tags: angular, internet-explorer

When running, a console error is thrown: "variable undefined in strict mode" and the app gets stuck.
In other browsers, the problem does not occur

the error's stack:

```
 'ReferenceError: Variable undefined in strict mode
       at SearchDeviceComponent (http://localhost:4200/default~centermind- 
   core-centermind-core-module~map-links-window-links-window-module~settings- 
   setting~706c08bd.js:448814:9)
   at createClass (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:68533:13)
   at createDirectiveInstance (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:68402:5)
   at createViewNodes (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:69628:21)
   at createEmbeddedView (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:69536:5)
   at TemplateRef_.prototype.createEmbeddedView (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:68117:9)
   at ViewContainerRef_.prototype.createEmbeddedView (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:67983:9)
   at NgIf.prototype._updateView (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:14001:21)
   at ngIf.set (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:13970:13)
   at updateProp (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:68678:5)"'
```

I removed the *ngIf directives in the search-base template,
  the problem is not solved.

Comment: Do you have any errors or warnings when you run `ng build --prod`?

Comment: No. There was no error.

Comment: Is it possible to paste source code from `SearchDeviceComponent`?

Comment: And which Edge version are you using?

Comment: 1. searchDeviceComponent extends anther component, maybe that figure could help.                                                                                                    
2.The template is very long, maybe you can target a specific code style that you suspect.

Comment: sorry, I am in IE11, not in Edge.

Comment: Which version of the Angular version are you using? please check the Polyfill file and ensure you have uncommented the related imports for the IE browser. If still not working, can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: when upgraded to Angular 7, we changed "import 'classlist/classlist.js';"
to "import 'classlist.js';". I do not know if the app stopped running in IE before or after the change.

Comment: If we want to import classlist.js, we need to Run `npm install --save classlist.js` first. After upgrading to angular 7 and import the classlist.js, whether it solved the problem?

Comment: I already have the library. the version is ''1.1.20150312".

Comment: I have tried to create a sample on my side, it works well, can't reproduce the issue. can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I discovered that the problem is in a general variable declaration:
>   decalre let self; and in the constructor: self = this;
>
> I removed the 'declare' keyword and the problem was resolved. Can
>   someone explain me what was the problem?

Angular is a TypeScript-based open-source web application framework, if we want to declare variables, we could use the let, const and var keyword, more detail information about TypeScript, please check [this article](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html).

Answer (score 0):

After working for hours, I discovered that the problem  is in a general variable declaration:
decalre let self;
and in the constructor:
self = this;

I removed the 'declare' keyword and the problem was resolved.
Can someone explain me what was the problem?